Rotating matplotlib subplot with additional axes
I am currently struggling to create a 3-panel figure where the centre plot contains a contour plot and the top left and right panels show some lines. The thing is that all the plots are rotated 45 degrees clockwise.
The final plot should look similar to this, but rotated 45 degrees.

So rotating the central part was straightforward, based on the floating_axes example. Getting the other two axes to align is not so easy. I tried using AxesDivider and ax.inset_axes with no satisfactory results.
So the current state is as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import floating_axes


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))

plot_extents = 0, 1, 0, 1

# Create transformation for rotation
transform = Affine2D().rotate_deg(-45)
helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(transform, plot_extents)

ax = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 111, grid_helper=helper)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

aux_ax = ax.get_aux_axes(transform)
# cs = aux_ax.contourf(x1, x2, y)  # contour plot

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

ax_top = divider.append_axes(
    "top",
    0.8,
    pad=0.35,
    sharex=aux_ax,
    grid_helper=helper,
)
ax_left = divider.append_axes(
    "left",
    0.8,
    pad=0.35,
    sharey=aux_ax,
    grid_helper=helper,
)

plt.show()


Which gives the following result:

Is there a nice way to align the panels?
